# C++ Simple Variant Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm attempting to create a list of objects using the variant boost.

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;   

class CSquare;

class CRectangle {
public:
  CRectangle();
};

class CSquare {
public:
  CSquare();
};

int main()
{   typedef variant<CRectangle,CSquare, bool, int, string> object;

    list<object> List;

    List.push_back("Hello World!");
    List.push_back(7);
    List.push_back(true);
    List.push_back(new CSquare());
    List.push_back(new CRectangle ());

    cout << "List Size is: " << List.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the following error is produced:

```
/tmp/ccxKh9lz.o: In function `main':
testing.C:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `CSquare::CSquare()'
testing.C:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `CRectangle::CRectangle()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I realise that everything would be fine if i used the form:

```
CSquare x;
CRectangle y;
List.push_back("Hello World!");
List.push_back(7);
List.push_back(true);
List.push_back(x);
List.push_back(y);
```

But i would like to avoid that form if at all possible, since i would like to keep my objects unnamed. This is an **important** requirement for my system - is there any way i can avoid using named objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just need to change a few things and it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;   

class CRectangle
{
public:
 CRectangle() {}
};

class CSquare
{
public:
 CSquare() {}
};

int main()
{
 typedef variant<CRectangle, CSquare, bool, int, string> object;
 list<object> List;
 List.push_back(string("Hello World!"));
 List.push_back(7);
 List.push_back(true);
 List.push_back(CSquare());
 List.push_back(CRectangle());

 cout << "List Size is: " << List.size() << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Specifically, you needed to define the CRectangle and CSquare constructors (that's why you were getting a linker error) and to use `CSquare()` rather than `new CSquare()` etc. Also, `"Hello World!"` has type `const char *`, so you need to write `string("Hello World!")` when passing it to `push_back` or it will get implicitly converted to `bool` here (not what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  List.push_back(new CSquare()); just write

```
List.push_back(CSquare());
```

And also write defination of your constructor

Answer (score 0):

You forget to implement the constructors `CRectangle::CRectangle()` and `CSquare::CSquare()`.

Either implement them somewhere outside the class such as:

```
CRectangle::CRectangle()
{ 
    // :::
};
```

... or implement them inside the class:

```
class CRectangle {
public:
  CRectangle()
  { 
    // :::
  }
};
```

... or remove the constructor declarations altogether:

```
class CRectangle {
public:
};
```